# apply the horizontal scrollview for canvas

Tags: android

Hi i am displaying some lines on canvas.Now i want to apply horizontal scrollview for those lines.Please give me some (code) suggestions.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to define scrollview in your class,

```
    ScrollView sc=new ScrollView(this);
sc.measure(400, 10);
        int width = sc.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = sc.getMeasuredHeight();
        int left = 100;
        int top = 100;
           sc.layout(0, top, left + width, top + height);
```

Then you have to set layout params for that.

Then you can draw it on your canvas like this method:

```
sc.draw(canvas); //canvas is your canvas name on which you are drawing
```

### Edited

The other way I think very simple for you is take one scrollview in your main layout and include your view inside it. So it will not need todraw scroll in it.

Comment: chirag in canvas i am not able to add scrollview